# OS updates on 1-4-2018 messed up system

Tags: updates

The OS worked fine until, updating & rebooting Ubuntu 16.04.3 on 1-4-2018. The launcher will not open a selected program and will disappear off screen for a few seconds along with top bar, once mouse pointer selects a program, (Launcher is not set to auto-hide). Only way to access anything is via the terminal. If a program was run via terminal commands it would load, then the program's window would disappear without touching its window. Re-installed Ubuntu twice and it worked fine until I updated the system via Software Updater after the re-installs. Installed other Linux distros, and they work fine. Ran Ubuntu on that laptop for 2 years without any issues. What happened to latest updates that messed up the OS?

Comment: Seems to be related to new [bug 1741447](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1741447). You can try MATE DE (`ubuntu-mate-desktop` package) while waiting for patch :)